# GUI to database app using python3 and sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, user-interface

I am trying to use a gui to display data in sqlite3.I have successfully created the  gui and know where the data base is. I am having trouble  because after I fill out the gui table i get this error.

Error binding parameter 0-unsupported type.

Here is  where the problemn lies.

```
#  def submit():
conn = sqlite3.connect('interface_data.db')
#Create Cursor
c=conn.cursor()
insert into table
c.execute("INSERT INTO Interfaces VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(first_name,last_name,adress,city,stateloc,zip,phone))
{
    'first_name':first_name.get(),
    'last_name':last_name.get(),
    'adresses':adress.get(),
    'city':city.get(),
    'statelocloc':stateloc.get(),
    'zip':zipcode.get(),
    'Phone':phone.get()
}
```

I AM almost finish please help!!!!!

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2s6l.png)

Comment: It says "unsupported type" for the first parameter (i.e. `first_name`). That means `first_name` contains something that is not a simple value. Check what `first_name.get()` actually returns, it's probably not a string.